# Window Phone 8 submit post form with an image

Tags: c#, html, wpf, windows-runtime

I am working on window phone 8.0 and I have a problem when trying to submit a post request from mobile phone to a website. The input named "file" and it accepts only image file.

```
<form action="upmeme" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" class="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
   <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

or you can visite here: **[this website](http://cheanh.9ozz.com/upmeme)**

I used PhotoPicker to choose the photo from libary and keep it into "photo" `Stream photo = e.ChosenPhoto;` and it worked perfectly.

Now I need to upload the photo and submit the form above .This is my code called to send a post request, but it does not work, the response is the same as before summiting

```
photo.Position = 0;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);           
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();  
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent(); 
form.Add(new StreamContent(photo),"file");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, form); 
string responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I tried to look arround the Internet and I found the same result as my mine. Is my code wrong somewhere?

Comment: I have implemented some simple HTTP classes for uploading files, have a look at http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http, chapter "HTTP POST"

Answer (score 1):

**Retrieve the bitmap image:**

```
public async void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var imageFile = args.Files[0] as StorageFile;
        // Ensure the stream is disposed once the image is loaded
        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
            ImageControl.Source = bitmapImage;

            await _viewModel.Upload(imageFile);
        }               
    }
}
```

**Create the file stream:**

```
internal async Task Upload(Windows.Storage.StorageFile file)
{
    var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    fileStream.Seek(0);

    var reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
    await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);

    Globals.MemberId = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[Globals.PROFILE_KEY];
    var userName = "Rico";
    var sex = 1;
    var url = string.Format("{0}{1}?memberid={2}&name={3}&sex={4}", Globals.URL_PREFIX, "api/Images", Globals.MemberId, userName,sex);
    byte[] image = new byte[fileStream.Size];

    await UploadImage(image, url);
}
```

**Create a memory stream from the image:**

```
public async Task UploadImage(byte[] image, string url)
{
    Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(image);
    HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());

    Uri resourceAddress = null;
    Uri.TryCreate(url.Trim(), UriKind.Absolute, out resourceAddress);
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Post, resourceAddress);
    request.Content = streamContent;

    var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(cts.Token);
}
```

Comment: this version uses for window phone 8.1, doesn't it? I am working on 8.0 and I think it doesn't suport your script, any way thanks for your anwser.