# Timeout issues with C# httpclient

Tags: c#, file-upload, dotnet-httpclient

My problem is with uploading big files with httpclient postasync method. It times out and so on. I did find this great blog post about httpwebrequest (http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2014/01/14/tackling-timeout-issues-when-uploading-large-files-with-httpwebrequest/) which tells how to deal with timeout issues when using httpwebrequest. However the current request is done with httpclient so I'm wondering if there is any way to do it with httpclient?

In the other posts there are ideas to split the chunk of data. However I don't see any reason to do extra work if the timeout can be disabled for transfer part of the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best strategy to upload large file using HttpClient in a low memory windows phone device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016729/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-upload-large-file-using-httpclient-in-a-low-memory)

Comment: Is there no answer to this? I don't see any reason splitting the data if this can be done easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to do this with httpclient. Httpclient uses httpwebrequest so the only way to do this is by using httpwebrequest. Which seems to be working well like in the Thomas's blog.